# 3D Multipatch feature class to 3D GeoJSON in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: geojson, arcgis-pro, multipatch

I have generated some building blocks in CityEngine and exported them as "Multipatch feature class" in GeoDataBase, then I imported them into ArcGIS Pro and tried to convert them into 3D GeoJSON format, but it turns out that the "Feature to JSON" tool available in Toolbox does not accept Multipatch feature class, only polygons, polylines, and points. So I first tried to convert the 3D Multipatch feature into Multipolygon, I have tried "Multipatch footprint", which turned out to be losing all the Z values of the building floors. And "Feature Vertices To Points" and "Multipatch to Raster" also does not suit my purpose (I think).

So how can I convert Multipatch to Multipolygon without losing Z-value, or convert Multipatch into GeoJSON format in general?

Answer (score 1):

From https://geojson.org/:

> GeoJSON supports the following geometry types: **Point**, **LineString**,
>   **Polygon**, **MultiPoint**, **MultiLineString**, and **MultiPolygon**. Geometric
>   objects with additional properties are Feature objects. Sets of
>   features are contained by FeatureCollection objects.

I'm no GeoJSON expert but when I read this I think what you want is not supported at the moment.

Comment: Great thanks for your response. Yet if I can somehow manage to convert MultiPatch into MultiPolygon first, without losing the Z-value, it will also do the job. I used "Multipatch Footprint", but it removes all the z-values. I am just wondering if there is some way out there that can convert MultiPatch into MultiPolygon without losing Z-value?

Comment: @Janine I don't think I know an easy answer. If you have cubes you could extract all coordinates, group where they are the same in 2D and keep only the lowest z, generate a hull around the coordinates. But this does not work with complex geometries with overhangs.